# Webrtc based video chat , video stream not generated in firefox

Tags: html, webrtc, peerjs

I have implemented webrtc based video chat using peerjs.It works fine in chrome but I am not able to generate the stream in firefox. navigator.getUserMedia has been used to generate audio-video stream as follows:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio : true,
            video : true
        }, function(stream) {       
            window.localStream = stream;
        }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
});
```

When i use above promise in firefox, neither it goes into successcallback nor in errorcallback.

Comment: What promise? The code shown works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

A few things: navigator.*GetUserMedia() is deprecated; you want [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

peerjs is (IIRC) unmaintained and incompatible with a number of aspects of current spec.  It has been forked by NTT/Skyway and that version should be usable.

The above code does not seem to be a Promise... (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() does return a Promise).

For examples that work with Firefox, see our rough test page at https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing, especially https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html.  For a very-compatible shim layer, see adapter.js